# GWTP : events and nested presenters

Tags: events, nested, gwtp, presenter

I have some problems with events in GWTP.

I have a MainPresenter which extends TabContainerPresenter.
This presenter is linked to a MainView which contains some ui components + some com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Tab : HomeTab, ContactTab and so on.

MainPresenter is supposed to react to some events "MyEvent"
MyEvent has a corresponding MyHandler and has been created following those good practices http://arcbees.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/gwt-platform-event-best-practice/

When I fire an event from a ui component of MainView like this :

```
MyEvent.fire(this, new MyEventContext(..));
```

I correctly catch the event in MainPresenter.

But When I do exactly the same in one of the "Tab Presenter", the event is not caught by the MainPresenter.

For example, in HomePresenter which is the "HomeTab" of MainPresenter, when I do

```
MyEvent.fire(this, new MyEventContext(..));
```

I can catch the event from the HomePresenter but not from the MainPresenter.

Any idea?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you respect those rules:

1. The EventBus you inject in your View is `com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus` (and not `com.google.gwt.event.shared.EventBus`)
2. In the Presenter that handles the event (HomePresenter or MainPresenter), register to the event using the `addRegisteredHandler` method, inside the `onBind` lifecyle method:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onBind() {
       super.onBind();

       addRegisteredHandler(MyEvent.getType(), this);
   }
   ```

I don't know what is your particular mistake that you've done. To help you, I made [a quick proof of concept](https://github.com/spg/GWTP-Samples/tree/spg_event_tabbed_presenters) which shows that events can be sent from a tabbed presenter to a TabContainerPresenter. Clone this project, and head to the #!settingsPage. You'll see two "Fire true" and "Fire false" buttons, which will fire events that will be caught by the ApplicationPresenter.

Comment: First, let me thank you for this awesome POC, it is an excellent basis to understand what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me thank you for this awesome POC, it is an excellent basis to understand what was going wrong. I saw that I actually did not use GWTP in the good way.

The root problem was that I had 2 differents eventBus
I saw it by trying

```
Log.info("eventBus: "+eventBus)
```

in the MainPresenter and in the HomePresenter. The logs showed that they did not have the same hashcode.

This was due to the fact that sometimes, I accessed directly the EventBus by doing:

```
EventBus.Util.getInstance();
```

Whereas the placeManager instantiated with:

```
DelayedBindRegistry.bind(GWT.create(MyInjector.class))
```